# How can I list all lightweight tags?

Tags: git, git-tag

I want to list all of the lightweight tags in my repository; the best I can think of involves combining `git for-each-ref`, `grep`, and `cut`, but it seems like it'll be kind of fiddly...

(While we're at it, we might as well talk about the same thing for annotated tags: someone is sure to end up here wondering about that at some point.)

**Edit:**

By `lightweight` tags, I meant those tag refs that do *not* refer to tag objects. (In other words, unannotated tags.)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

All the lightweight tags are in the `refs/tags/` namespace and can be enumerated with, e.g.:

```
git for-each-ref --format '%(refname:short)' refs/tags/
```

or:

```
git show-ref --tags
```

As for annotated tags, well, the trick here—it affects the "lightweight" tags part too—is that an annotated tag is actually an object in the git repository, *but*, there's a lightweight tag that *points to* that object, that lets you get at the annotated tag by its tag name.<sup>1</sup>  So it's really a *pair* of things: a lightweight tag, plus the in-repo annotated tag object, that makes it "not a lightweight tag", except for that stubborn fact that it *is* a lightweight tag at the same time!

Thus, it boils down to: find *all* lightweight tags, then optionally select only tags pointing to commits or tags pointing to tag-objects depending on the behavior you want, then go on to emit the tag name.

There's a long example in the `git-for-each-ref` documentation of writing an entire script in the `--format` string and using `eval` to execute it (or you could pipe to `sh` to execute, at the cost of one extra process).  I usually find it simpler to pipe the output of `git for-each-ref` into a `while read ...` loop:

```
git for-each-ref refs/tags/ --format '%(objecttype) %(refname:short)' |
    while read ty name; do [ $ty = commit ] && echo $name; done
```

which prints all **lightweight-only** tags.

Compare with:

```
git for-each-ref refs/tags/ --format '%(objecttype) %(refname:short)' |
    while read ty name; do [ $ty = tag ] && echo $name; done
```

which prints all **annotated** tags (or more precisely, "lightweight-that-are-annotated" tags).

Note that a tag can (conceivably—there's no actual use case for this right now, as far as I know) point to something other than a commit or a tag; it's up to you whether to do something with a tag pointing directly to a `tree` or `blob`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Without the lightweight tag, you would not be able to refer to annotated tag `annotag` using the name `annotag`—not without going through all the search effort that `git fsck` uses to find dangling objects, at least.  Moreover, if you delete the lightweight tag, the annotated tag object may get garbage-collected.  You can make one tag object point to another tag object to keep it in the repo (i.e., inhibit the gc) without an external name for the second tag object, as long as the first one has an external name.  That's definitely an odd thing to do though.

Interestingly, the internal format for the annotated tag contains the external name, so one can use this technique to protect "old" annotated tags, hide them by removing their lightweight tags, and then later restore the original lightweight tag.  Whether anyone can come up with a *use* for this, though... :-)

Comment: I must admit I'm mystified as to the purpose of that `--shell` example in `git-for-each-ref(1)`; why would one ever want to construct a huge, monolithic shell script in memory rather than using the output incrementally in a pipeline/loop like this?

Comment: I'm not really sure.  Perhaps it's just to demo the quoting aspects (you can get output quoted for use in perl, python, and shell)...  There are some cases where the shell spawns off a loop into a subprocess, creating issues with keeping variable values after the loop terminates.  Maybe it's meant for those.

Comment: I would just replace those while loops by `awk`: `git for-each-ref refs/tags/ --format '%(objecttype) %(refname:short)' | awk '$1 == "tag" {print $2}'`

Comment: @CiroSantilli: yes, that's faster / better for this case.  (Assuming one has awk, some Windows users might not.)

Comment: "Assuming one has awk, some Windows users might not": any Windows would have those, provided they add to their path `C:\path\to\PortableGit-2.6.3-64-bit\usr\bin` . Although the use of double-quotes is needed in some places: `git for-each-ref refs/tags/ --format "%(objecttype) %(refname:short)" | awk '$1 == "tag" {print $2}'`. That works just fine in my plain CMD session.

Comment: @Shalomi90 I will get to it later today, probably, as I scan through new questions.

Answer (score 13):

To list only **lightweight** tags:

```
git for-each-ref refs/tags | grep commit
```

To list only **annotated** tags:

```
git for-each-ref refs/tags | grep -v commit
```

Explanation:

`git for-each-ref` lists all refs: *heads*, *remotes*, *stash* and *tags*

`git for-each-ref refs/tags` lists only *tags* refs.

`| grep commit` lists only those lines which contain the word *commit*. These are tags pointing to a commit and are thus lightweight tags.

`| grep -v commit` lists only those lines which do not contain the word *commit*. These are tags pointing to a tag and are thus annotated tags.

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing the other answer and its comments, if you're using bash:

```
function git-lightweight-tags() { 
    git for-each-ref refs/tags/ --format '%(objecttype) %(refname:short)' | awk '$1 == "commit" {print $2}' ; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that you can tag (lightweight and annotated) blobs and trees also.

Therefore `git for-each-ref refs/tags | grep -v commit` will not only list annotated tags, but also tags to blobs and trees.

I suggest to use grep for the word 'tag' to find annotated tags:

`git for-each-ref refs/tags | grep -w tag`.

Don't forget `-w`, otherwise you will find the substring `tag` also for lightweight tags.

Comment: Hmm ... I think this would still match tags like `foo/tag`. (Also, it's not actually an answer to my question.)

Comment: @SamB: right, sorry, my comment was not a reaction to your original question. My comment was targeting to answers suggesting to grep for 'commit'

Answer (score 0):

Using `git for-each-ref` and `awk`

#### Annotated Tags

```bash
git for-each-ref refs/tags |
  awk '$2~/tag/{print $3}'
```

#### Light-weight tags

```bash
git for-each-ref refs/tags |
  awk '$2~/commit/{print $3}'
```

First field is the hash, second the type, third is the name of the ref