# Distinguish between lightweight and annotated tags in JGit

Tags: jgit

I'm trying to figure out how to distinguish between lightweight and annotated tags in JGit without catching any exceptions. In my special case, I need that distinction for getting all tag names of a given commit.

```
public List<String> getTagNamesOfCommit(String commitHash) throws Exception {
  List<String> tagNames = new ArrayList<>();
  RevWalk walk = new RevWalk(repository);
  List<Ref> tagList = git.tagList().call();
  for (Ref tag : tagList) {
    ObjectId peeledObjectId = tag.getPeeledObjectId();
    try {
      // Try to get annotated tag
      RevTag refetchedTag = walk.parseTag(tag.getObjectId());
      RevObject peeled = walk.peel(refetchedTag.getObject());
      if (peeled.getId().getName().equals(commitHash)) {
        tagNames.add(Repository.shortenRefName(tag.getName()));
      }
    } catch(IncorrectObjectTypeException notAnAnnotatedTag) {
      // Tag is not annotated. Yes, that's how you find out ...
      if (tag.getObjectId().getName().equals(commitHash)) {
        tagNames.add(Repository.shortenRefName(tag.getName()));
      }
    }
  }
  walk.close();
  return tagNames;
}
```

This is an equivalent solution as contained in an answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29892210/get-message-of-tags-using-jgit)

```
RevTag tag;
try {
  tag = revWalk.parseTag(ref.getObjectId());
  // ref points to an annotated tag
} catch(IncorrectObjectTypeException notAnAnnotatedTag) {
  // ref is a lightweight (aka unannotated) tag
}
```

The class `org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Ref` has the method `getPeeledObjectId()` which should return the id of the commit in case of an annotated tag.

```
* return if this ref is an annotated tag the id of the commit (or tree or
*        blob) that the annotated tag refers to; {@code null} if this ref
*        does not refer to an annotated tag.
```

This way I could check for null, which is much nicer than catching an exception. Unfortunately the method returns `null` in every case.

Two questions:

1. Is there anything wrong with the use of `git.tagList().call()`?
2. What would be the correct way to find out if a tag is an annotated one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run the example [ReadTagForName](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/api/ReadTagFromName.java) in the [jgit-cookbook](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/) the output contains the following:

```
Commit: (class org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevCommit)commit a3033aec313556ba4e1ef55a66167a35432a4bc1 1369660983 ------p
Tag: (class org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevTag)tag 25f629b5e8ddfabd55650c05ffbb5199633b6df0 ------p
```

So you should be able to check for the actual class of the `Ref` object that is returned. If it is "RevCommit" it is a lightweight tag, and if it is "RevTag" it seems to be an annotated tag.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. The class distinction looks better than exception handling. It's a bit confusing that they implemented the Ref class, which holds the tag name and you then have to parse for the object again to get a RevObject on which then the distinction can be made. I miss a real Tag object, that holds everything (isAnnotated, name, commit reference etc.) Anyways, you answer seems to be the best solution for my problem.