# Git tagging: Time-based or Commit-based

Tags: git, git-tag

When I create a tag (either lightweight or annotated) and provide no commit id, does Git record the tag as "a point in time" when the tag was created?

Or does it tag the latest commit in my branch and the "time" associated with that tag is the time of the latest commit?

Does it matter if the tag is lightweight or annotated?

[The docs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) say:

> A lightweight tag is very much like a branch that doesn’t change – it’s just a pointer to a specific commit.

So, it seems clear that a lightweight tag just points to a commit. But what about an annotated tag. The docs are clear about various things you can do with an annotated tag (including adding a message, signing, etc), but don't specify that if it is a pointer to a commit or not.

Comment: It was nice that I posted this to prove to a co-worker that he was wrong, and that my rep is getting chipped away by downvotes without comment. </rant>

Comment: Probably there are some who don't understand that there are two types of tags in Git -- lightweight and annotated.

Comment: It could be argued that this was answered previously, but the other answers were biased in terms of _always_ using annotated tags, which imho is the wrong solution in many use cases -- Maven, for instance.  [Here is the other similar question marked as answered.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4971746/325452)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lightweight tag is a reference that records an object SHA-1.  The object "should" be a commit, but nothing in git forces this.  Therefore it's possible for a lightweight tag to point to a tree or a blob.

References don't have time stamps.  (The ref's "reflog", which is the log of every *change* made to that reference, does have time stamps.  This includes an entry for when the ref itself was created.  However, reflogs need not exist for any particular ref; reflog entries expire after a configurable time, default 90 days; and it's up to the programs that update the refs to make sure they update the reflog as well.  All of git's internal commands do; for non-git external scripts, it depends on whether they're well-written.)

An annotated tag consists of *two* entries: a reference—a lightweight tag—and an underlying git object of type "tag".  If you pretty-print a tag object, you'll see a timestamp in the tag:

```
$ git cat-file -p v2.5.0 | sed -e 's/@/ /' -e 7q
object a17c56c056d5fea0843b429132904c429a900229
type commit
tag v2.5.0
tagger Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1438025401 -0700

Git 2.5
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
```

The `object` line gives the SHA-1 of the target of the tag, and the `type` line gives the type of that object.  This *should* be either a commit or another tag (i.e., annotated tag object).  Again, nothing prohibits this from pointing directly to a tree or blob.

The `tagger` line shows who created the tag, and the time (according to the machine and/or any other overrides) the tagger created the tag.  So you do get a tag-creation time stamp here.

Note that the target of the tag (lightweight *or* annotated) is simply the SHA-1 you specify (default HEAD).  Of course, if you target a new lightweight tag at an existing annotated tag object, what you get is basically an annotated tag (although it's weird since the lightweight tag name, `refs/tags/name`, won't match the name in the `tag` line of the annotated tag object).

---

Short answer (if not too late): yes, there's a time stamp in an annotated tag, and this does depend on it being annotated.

Comment: There is more than a timestamp on an annotated tag. It also contains the committer id plus perhaps some additional info. And, there is some cost in terms of additional Git indexing.

Comment: @ingyhere: sure, that's why I showed one with the top of a GPG signature. You can put almost arbitrary data into an annotated tag object, though Git doesn't have a built in way to add anything other than message and signatures.