# What is the difference between an annotated and unannotated tag?

Tags: git, tags, git-tag

If I want to tag the current commit. I know both of the following command lines work:

```bash
git tag <tagname>
```

and

```bash
git tag -a <tagname> -m '<message>'
```

What is the difference between these commands?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In what circumstances should I add the -a flag to the git tag command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092640/in-what-circumstances-should-i-add-the-a-flag-to-the-git-tag-command)

Comment: @Thilo This is *not* an exact duplicate. The referenced question is about when to annotate, not about the related flags.

Comment: This is very well explained in Git's documentation: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Tagging

Comment: TLDR unannotated: commit; annotated: commit, author, date, (optional) comment

Comment: @SamyDindane if Gits docs would be more clear in search results and would show up higher than stack results, and if gits docs were as useful as stack was, then more of us would probably use git docs, but instead i always choose the stack results.  Thanks for linking the git docs here or i wouldnt have found it as useful :-). this is the part i needed to know `The -m specifies a tagging message, which is stored with the tag. If you don’t specify a message for an annotated tag, Git launches your editor so you can type it in.`. So ill use `-a` without `-m` here out cause i prefer vim.

Answer (score 423):

#### TL;DR

The difference between the commands is that one provides you with a tag message while the other doesn't. An annotated tag has a message that can be displayed with git-show(1), while a tag without annotations is just a named pointer to a commit.

#### More About Lightweight Tags

According to the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging): "To create a lightweight tag, don’t supply any of the -a, -s, or -m options, just provide a tag name". There are also some different options to write a message on annotated tags:

- When you use `git tag <tagname>`, Git will create a tag at the current revision but will not prompt you for an annotation. It will be tagged without a message (this is a lightweight tag).
- When you use `git tag -a <tagname>`, Git will prompt you for an annotation unless you have also used the -m flag to provide a message.
- When you use `git tag -a -m <msg> <tagname>`, Git will tag the commit and annotate it with the provided message.
- When you use `git tag -m <msg> <tagname>`, Git will behave as if you passed the -a flag for annotation and use the provided message.

Basically, it just amounts to whether you want the tag to have an annotation and some other information associated with it or not.

Comment: Is there a difference between a tag "annotation" and a commit message?

Comment: @SteveBennett Yes. A tag annotation is not a commit message. You can't see it with git-log(1); you need to use git-show(1).

Comment: The difference between "annotated" and "lightweight" tags goes beyond message. You can have annotated tag without a message (`git tag -a <tag> -m ''`), but an annotated tag always has *tagger* (author) and *date*.

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen That's quite a big deal, thank you. … the message bit I'd almost never care about (because tag names in my experience are descriptive of a point in process anyway, and a message is pretty unnecessary). The tagger and the date matter to me, though.

Comment: Same for me. Version tags usually have pretty useless messages (can it say more than the name? What for?). Unfortunately, this top-voted answer does not mention this difference.

Comment: Another important thing to note is that when you push your tags to a remote repository using ``git push --follow-tags``, only the annotated tags will be pushed.

Comment: Complementing @Xatoo comment, `git push origin --tags` push both types of tags, annotated and lightweight tags.

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen The tag command with `-m` and no value returns for me `error: switch 'm' requires a value`. Should there be a whitespace between `''`?

Comment: See here for how to update your global **.gitconfig** file to push annotated tags to the remote with every `git push`: [How do you push a tag to a remote repository using Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195859/how-do-you-push-a-tag-to-a-remote-repository-using-git/26438076#26438076)

Answer (score 331):

**Push annotated tags, keep lightweight local**

`man git-tag` says:

> Annotated tags are meant for release while lightweight tags are meant for private or temporary object labels.

And certain behaviors do differentiate between them in ways that this recommendation is useful e.g.:

- annotated tags can contain a message, creator, and date different than the commit they point to. So you could use them to describe a release without making a release commit.

  Lightweight tags don't have that extra information, and don't need it, since you are only going to use it yourself to develop.
- [git push --follow-tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26438076/895245) will only push annotated tags
- `git describe` without command line options only sees annotated tags

**Internals differences**

- both lightweight and annotated tags are a file under `.git/refs/tags` that contains a SHA-1
- for lightweight tags, the SHA-1 points directly to a commit:

  ```
  git tag light
  cat .git/refs/tags/light
  ```

  prints the same as the HEAD's SHA-1.

  So no wonder they cannot contain any other metadata.
- annotated tags point to a tag object in the object database.

  ```
  git tag -as -m msg annot
  cat .git/refs/tags/annot
  ```

  contains the SHA of the annotated tag object:

  ```
  c1d7720e99f9dd1d1c8aee625fd6ce09b3a81fef
  ```

  and then we can get its content with:

  ```
  git cat-file -p c1d7720e99f9dd1d1c8aee625fd6ce09b3a81fef
  ```

  sample output:

  ```
  object 4284c41353e51a07e4ed4192ad2e9eaada9c059f
  type commit
  tag annot
  tagger Ciro Santilli <your@mail.com> 1411478848 +0200

  msg
  -----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
  Version: GnuPG v1.4.11 (GNU/Linux)

  <YOUR PGP SIGNATURE>
  -----END PGP SIGNAT
  ```

  And this is how it contains extra metadata. As we can see from the output, the metadata fields are:

  - the object it points to
  - the type of object it points to. Yes, [tag objects can point to any other type of object like blobs, not just commits](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/8266).
  - the name of the tag
  - tagger identity and timestamp
  - message. Note how the PGP signature is just appended to the message

  A more detailed analysis of the format is present at: [What is the format of a git tag object and how to calculate its SHA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986615/what-is-the-format-of-a-git-tag-object-and-how-to-calculate-its-sha/52193441#52193441)

**Bonuses**

- Determine if a tag is annotated:

  ```
  git cat-file -t tag
  ```

  Outputs

  - `commit` for lightweight, since there is no tag object, it points directly to the commit
  - `tag` for annotated, since there is a tag object in that case
- List only lightweight tags: [How can I list all lightweight tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031201/how-can-i-list-all-lightweight-tags)

Answer (score 64):

The **big** difference is perfectly explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971746/why-should-i-care-about-lightweight-vs-annotated-tags).

Basically, **lightweight tags** are just pointers to specific commits. **No further information is saved**; on the other hand, **annotated tags** are **regular objects**, which have an author and a date and can be referred because they have their own SHA key.

If knowing **who** tagged **what** and **when** is relevant for you, then use annotated tags. If you **just want to tag a specific point in your development**, no matter who and when did that, then lightweight tags are good enough.

Normally you'd go for annotated tags, but it is really up to the Git master of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Another difference is when `git tag -a foo` fails, because there is already a tag `foo/bar`, as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32850142/6309).

With Git 2.42 (Q3 2023), "[`git tag`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6d2a88c7289b56999426354f44b536255b57c5c8/Documentation/git-tag.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag))</sup> learned to leave the `"$GIT_DIR/TAG_EDITMSG"` file when the command failed, so that the user can salvage what they typed.
That git tag message file would not exist for a lightweight tag.

See [commit 08c12ec](https://github.com/git/git/commit/08c12ec1d0444c9ea7cf24b7157aa158f3f641f4), [commit 669c11d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/669c11de85d0071a31de0e49f6e5b602fd54a9ef), [commit 719515f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/719515fdd0a951f51751e12fefa79cb25c6ae15d) (16 May 2023) by [Kristoffer Haugsbakk (`LemmingAvalanche`)](https://github.com/LemmingAvalanche).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6d2a88c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6d2a88c7289b56999426354f44b536255b57c5c8), 13 Jun 2023)</sup>

> ### [`tag`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/08c12ec1d0444c9ea7cf24b7157aa158f3f641f4): keep the message file in case ref transaction fails
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Kristoffer Haugsbakk</sup>

> The ref transaction can fail after the user has written their tag message.
> In particular, if there exists a tag `foo/bar` and [`git tag -a foo`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/08c12ec1d0444c9ea7cf24b7157aa158f3f641f4/Documentation/git-tag.txt#L60)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag#Documentation/git-tag.txt--a))</sup> is said then the command will only fail once it tries to write `refs/tags/foo`, which is after the file has been unlinked.
>
> Hold on to the message file for a little longer so that it is not unlinked before the fatal error occurs.

And:

> ### [`doc`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/719515fdd0a951f51751e12fefa79cb25c6ae15d): tag: document `TAG_EDITMSG`
>
> <sup>Suggested-by: Junio C Hamano</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Kristoffer Haugsbakk</sup>

> Document `TAG_EDITMSG` which we have told the user about on unsuccessful command invocations since [commit 3927bbe](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3927bbe9a4d4033551dea39ac1abb9cdc45d822c) ("`tag`: delete `TAG_EDITMSG` only on successful tag", 2008-12-06, Git v1.6.1-rc2 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3a59bb22db24ff90c173ffb462fe67902a213d96)).
>
> Introduce this documentation since we are going to add tests for the lifetime of this file in the case of command failure and success.
>
> Use the documentation for `COMMIT_EDITMSG` from `git-commit.txt` as a template since these two files share the same purpose.[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32850142/6309)
>
> † 1: from [commit 3927bbe](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3927bbe9a4d4033551dea39ac1abb9cdc45d822c):
>
> ```
> “ This matches the behavior of COMMIT_EDITMSG, which stays around
>   in case of error.
> ```

`git tag` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/719515fdd0a951f51751e12fefa79cb25c6ae15d/Documentation/git-tag.txt#L384-L393):

> ### FILES
>
> #### `$GIT_DIR/TAG_EDITMSG`
>
> This file contains the message of an in-progress annotated
> tag. If `git tag` exits due to an error before creating an
> annotated tag then the tag message that has been provided by the
> user in an editor session will be available in this file, but
> may be overwritten by the next invocation of `git tag`.