# Create a tag in a GitHub repository

Tags: git, github, git-tag

I have a GitHub repository and I need to tag it.

I created a tag in a shell using the following command:

```
git tag 2.0
git tag
>>> 2.0
```

The tag does exist locally, but does not appear on GitHub.

How do I push this tag to GitHub?

Answer (score 2453, accepted):

You can create tags for GitHub by either using:

- the Git command line, or
- GitHub's web interface.

### Creating tags from the command line

To create a tag on your current branch, run this:

```
git tag <tagname>
```

If you want to include a description with your tag, add `-a` to create an [annotated tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11514075/what-is-the-difference-between-an-annotated-and-unannotated-tag):

```
git tag <tagname> -a
```

This will create a `local` tag with the current state of the branch you are on. When pushing to your remote repo, tags are NOT included by default. You will need to explicitly say that you want to push your tags to your remote repo:

```
git push origin --tags
```

From the [official Linux Kernel Git documentation for `git push`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html):

> ```
> --tags
> ```
>
> All refs under refs/tags are pushed, in addition to refspecs explicitly listed on the command line.

Or if you just want to push a single tag:

```
git push origin <tag>
```

See also my answer to [How do you push a tag to a remote repository using Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195859/push-a-tag-to-a-remote-repository-using-git/23217431#23217431) for more details about that syntax above.

### Creating tags through GitHub's web interface

You can find GitHub's instructions for this at their [Creating Releases help page](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-releases). Here is a summary:

1. Click the **releases** link on our repository page,

   [image: Screenshot 1]
2. Click on **Create a new release** or **Draft a new release**,

   [image: Screenshot 2]
3. Fill out the form fields, then click **Publish release** at the bottom,

   [image: Screenshot 3]
   [image: Screenshot 4]
4. After you create your tag on GitHub, you might want to fetch it into your local repository too:

   ```
   git fetch
   ```

Now next time, you may want to create one more tag within the same release from website. For that follow these steps:

Go to release tab

1. Click on edit button for the release
2. Provide name of the new tag ABC_DEF_V_5_3_T_2 and hit tab
3. After hitting tab, UI will show this message: Excellent! This tag will be created from the target when you publish this release. Also UI will provide an option to select the branch/commit
4. Select branch or commit
5. Check "This is a pre-release" checkbox for qa tag and uncheck it if the tag is created for Prod tag.
6. After that click on "Update Release"
7. This will create a new Tag within the existing Release.

Comment: @RandomDSdevel in github, release is just a tag. You can create tag from command line and push it to github remote. tag will appear as a release on githubs webpage.

Comment: @IuriG.:  Well, yes, but shouldn't you be able to create tags that don't automatically get picked up by GitHub as releases…?  (Back when I originally created the comment to which you responded and to whose response of yours _this_ one is a reply, tags at least _used_ to get turned into releases automatically, though I don't know if this is still the case or not&thinsp;going by the workflow explained in your answer hints at this no longer being true.  I submitted a support request to GitHub about this a while ago, but they had a bit of a support backlog back then, so my request was closed.)

Comment: Fwiw, for the Github web interface path, I can not see a Create or Draft new release button after clicking the releases link in Step 1.

Comment: @Snowcrash Do you have write access to the repository?

Comment: via Github interface you can create only Light-weight tags.

Comment: Unfortunately, the github interface doesn't allow you to tag a commit unless it was in the last 24 hours or the last 10 (? or so?) commits.

Comment: Would it be better to use `--follow-tags` instead of `--tag` when pushing? Otherwise all your weird, unrelated, unreferencable tags will be pushed. Maybe this option did not exist at the time of writing the answer.

Comment: I don't think this works any more. I don't see "Draft a new release" button any more.

Comment: And how do you git pull a tag?

Answer (score 200):

**Creating Tags**

Git uses two main types of tags: ***lightweight*** and ***annotated***.

**Annotated Tags**:

To create an annotated tag in Git you can just run the following simple commands on your terminal.

```
$ git tag -a v2.1.0 -m "xyz feature is released in this tag."
$ git tag
v1.0.0
v2.0.0
v2.1.0
```

The -m denotes message for that particular tag. We can write summary of features which is going to tag here.

**Lightweight Tags**:

The other way to tag commits is lightweight tag. We can do it in the following way:

```
$ git tag v2.1.0
$ git tag
v1.0.0
v2.0.0
v2.1.0
```

***Push Tag***

To push particular tag you can use below command:

```
git push origin v1.0.3
```

Or if you want to push all tags then use the below command:

```
git push --tags
```

***List all tags***:

To list all tags, use the following command.

```
git tag
```

Comment: Do you add the tag BEFORE or after the `git commit`?

Comment: I have added tag after git commit.

Comment: @garfbradaz When you make a tag it points to the latest commit, so after.

Comment: And how do you git pull a tag?

Answer (score 92):

In case you want to tag a specific commit like i do

Here's a command to do that :-

Example:

```
git tag -a v1.0 7cceb02 -m "Your message here"
```

Where `7cceb02` is the beginning part of the commit id.

You can then push the tag using `git push origin v1.0`.

You can do `git log` to show all the commit id's in your current branch.

Answer (score 91):

You just have to push the tag after you run the `git tag 2.0` command.

So just do `git push --tags` now.

Comment: I'd rather suggest to use `git push v2.0` instead of `--tags`, there might be other tags that should not be pushed.

Comment: That's only a problem if your local tags differ from your remote tags. They are easy to sync if that ever becomes a problem.

Comment: @kjdion84 No, that's also a problem if there are obsolete tags: All tags get always fetched and when someone uses `--tags`, it's hard to get rid of them.

Comment: or `git push origin v2.0`

Comment: I did the mistake of using tags!

Comment: @tschoppi you can use `git push --follow-tags` to ensure to only push tags related to commits you're actually pushing

Answer (score 20):

CAREFUL: In the command in [Lawakush Kurmi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18216991/create-a-tag-in-a-github-repository/48534947#48534947) (`git tag -a v1.0`) the `-a` flag is used. This flag tells Git to create an annotated flag. If you don't provide the flag (`i.e. git tag v1.0`) then it'll create what's called a lightweight tag.

---

Annotated tags are recommended, because they include a lot of extra information such as:

- the person who made the tag
- the date the tag was made
- a message for the tag

Because of this, you should always use annotated tags.

Answer (score 8):

It all depends what type of tag you want to create:

- If you want to create Annotated tags, to show extra metadata, you can do it in the following way: `git tag -a v1.0.0`.
- On the other hand, Lightweight tags are used to "bookmark" your commits for private use: `git tag v1.0.0`.

There are a few other tag functionalities such as:

- Listing tags - `git tag -l -n3`. The command lists all existing tags with maximum 3 lines of their tag message. By default -n only shows the first line.
- Tag details - `git show <tag_identifier>`. It shows all you need to know about a specific tag.
- Sorting tags - `git tag --sort=<type>`
- Publishing tags - `git push origin v1.0`. You can git push the tag individually, or you can run git push --tags which will push all tags at once.

Be sure to check this [tag related article](https://%20kolosek.com/git-tags/) for more relevant information.

Answer (score 7):

#### Using [Sourcetree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/)

Here are the simple steps to create a GitHub **Tag**, when you release build from master.

1. Open source_tree tab

   [image: step 1]
2. Right click on Tag sections from Tag which appear on left navigation section

   [image: step 2]
3. Click on New Tag()
4. A dialog appears to Add Tag and Remove Tag
5. Click on Add Tag from give name to tag (preferred version name of the code)

   [image: step 3]
6. If you want to push the TAG on remote, while creating the TAG ref: step 5 which gives checkbox **push TAG to origin**  check it and pushed tag appears on remote repository
7. In case while creating the TAG if you have forgotten to check the box **Push to origin**, you can do it later by right-clicking on the created TAG, click on **Push to** origin. 
   [image]

Comment: This answer explains how to create a local tag using Sourcetree, but the question is all about how to push the tag to the remote repository (GitHub in this case). You say to do this in step 6, but you left out the instructions for it.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane please check it now I have updated my answer, Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

If you use Intellij, you can use the menu "Git/New Tag", then CTRL-SHIFT-K and check the "push tags" checkbox at the bottom of the dialog.
This tag will appear in github, without creating a release.

[image: push commit with tags with intellij]

Answer (score 0):

For creating git tag you can simply run `git tag <tagname>` command by replacing  with the actual name of the tag.
Here is a complete tutorial on the basics of managing git tags: https://www.drupixels.com/blog/git-tags-create-push-remote-checkout-and-much-more

Answer (score 0):

For SourceTree users:

Right click on a commit and select "Tag...", then just be sure to check the "push tag" box.

[image]