# Git: checkout commit by commit and see all changes

Tags: git

I'm really not that comfortable with using command-line for `git`, so I prefer using `SourceTree`, but the UI can't solve one of my problems (it reloads all the time to the top).

Actually I want to checkout the very first commit of the `Swift` repository (which has almost 40k commits) and then only checkout every next commit by commit and see what has changed (I'd like to learn how the language was written).

Imagine one would iterate an array from index 0 without knowing if there is a successor and which information it might have (like commit id).

Is there any script or commands I could use?

**Update:**

I found the answer by myself [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33668818/4572536).

> **moving to next commit**
>
> ```
> function n() {
>     git log --reverse --pretty=%H master | grep -A 1 $(git rev-parse HEAD) | tail -n1 | xargs git checkout
> }
> ```
>
> **moving to previous commit**
>
> ```
> function p() {
>     git checkout HEAD^1
> }
> ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I move forward and backward between commits in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759791/how-do-i-move-forward-and-backward-between-commits-in-git)

Comment: Great.  See git is easy. Just learn git instead of using gui https://try.github.io/.

Comment: @khrm not that easy as at all. ^^ It took me a while to get these commands running as an alias. There are too many commands and parameters (it's just like `TeX`)

Comment: Yes. But I upvoted you because you showed perseverance. Yes, it's a bit difficult. But you can spend a day on it. and become quite proficient. Actually, that link is also not that great. Git has certain pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You could see the full history from first commit to last one. This will show all code changes (the diff). 
Just run:
`git log -p --reverse`

Comment: Imagine initial (or 1) commit and now the `Head` is at commit 10. Would will be the result? From 1 to 10 or from 9 to 10? I need something to show only the diffs from 9 to 10.

Comment: If you just want to see the last diff, you can run: `git log -1 -p HEAD`

Answer (score -1):

Just go to the clone of the repo on your machine.
You can get the SHA of the first commit from github. 
Copy the SHA of the  commit you want to checkout.
Do a `git checkout <SHA>`

Also you may do a `git checkout head~n` where n is the commit number counting down from `head` you want to refer to.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28671503/git-checkout-to-commit-number-n) :

Comment: That would be this: https://github.com/apple/swift/commit/18844bc65229786b96b89a9fc7739c0fc897905e. But how does he get from this one to the next child (of possibly n children)?

Comment: Just see the SHA of the next commit and repeat the same command.

Comment: This is ridiculous, you do know how long that will take to find every next commit from the initial one. I wasn't asking how to checkout a specific commit, but how to checkout the next commit without knowing any information of it (like indexing an array).

Comment: Well that was not too obvious from the question and since you said you are not to \o familiar with `git commands` !

Comment: I'm not familiar with them if someone would answer something like "use `checkout`" and see its docs how it works.

Comment: Use this then. But i do not agree with your point. Anyways try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28671503/git-checkout-to-commit-number-n