# github remote tag push without cloning repo

Tags: git, github, github-api

### How to edit tag in github, without cloning the repo from command line?

Example below shows how to list remote tags, without cloning the repo:

```
 $ git ls-remote --tags https://<TOKEN>@github.com/user/repo.git
 # 0afdaf971...09a  refs/tags/tagname
```

How to remotely edit/add/del new tag like example above without having to clone the repo?

```
git push origin :tagname
```

Requires of cloning the repo.

Is there a way to achieve it without cloning repo?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a tag in a GitHub repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18216991/create-a-tag-in-a-github-repository)

Comment: ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/18223354/592355 -> Creating tags through GitHub's web interface)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i need it from command line.

Comment: ..then you *must* clone! (what do you want to tag otherwise? ..a (non) empty folder/repository??) ..of course the work around: "call github from cmd" (with curl, when all else fails))

Comment: there is remote repository, I am looking for solution to remotely update the tag, to trigger builds.

Comment: @xerx593 I think that could be a solution! could you give example plz!

Comment: ..we have to elaborate, but starting: [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#create-a-release) (github rest api doc! section: create a release :)

Comment: @xerx593 Thanks for the guidance! found solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@xerx593

Thank you for pointing to the right direction, here is solution:

```
curl --user "username:password" --data '{"tag_name":"v1.1","target_commitish":"master"}' \
-X POST https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/releases
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this in a generic way in git (this may break in the future).

The following variables are used:

```
BRANCH_NAME # I think this can be anything
REPOSITORY_URL
COMMIT_HASH # The commit to tag
TAG_NAME # The name of the tag
```

For `git push` to work, you need to have a `.git` directory created as follows:

```
mkdir -p .git/objects .git/refs
echo 'ref: refs/heads/$BRANCH_NAME' > .git/HEAD
printf '[remote "origin"]\n    url = $REPOSITORY_URL'
```

Additionally, you need to have a "commit" object in the objects directory.  This file has a bit of information that's difficult to transfer over and re-create.  It's easier to just copy the file over (it's a small file).  The following will get the file:

```
mkdir -p output_directory/objects/${COMMIT_HASH:0:2}/
cp .git/objects/.git/objects/${COMMIT_HASH:0:2}/${COMMIT_HASH:2} output_directory/objects/${COMMIT_HASH:0:2}/${COMMIT_HASH:2}
```

And then when you're ready, you can copy this file to the new stub git repository in the `.git/objects/${COMMIT_HASH:0:2}/${COMMIT_HASH:2}` directory.

Then in the new stub git directory, push the new tag like this:

```
git push +${COMMIT_HASH}:refs/tags/${TAG_NAME}
```

Remember to set up your git credentials.  This can be done as follows:

```
git config credential.helper store
echo "https://$GIT_USERNAME:$GIT_PASSWORD@$GIT_REPOSITORY_DOMAIN" >  ~/.git-credentials
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this too.  If the commit you want to tag is the latest of a particular branch, you can download only that commit like this:

```
git clone --bare --single-branch --branch $BRANCH_NAME --depth=1 --filter=tree:0 --filter=blob:none --filter=object:type=commit $REPOSITORY_URL .git
```

This requires a later version of git which supports `--filter` and `--filter=object:type=commit`.  Besides the commits, this seems to also download the `hooks` directory, which on my repository is 40k (I think this is with an empty list of hooks).

Then you can tag it as usual:

```
git push origin +$BRANCH_NAME:refs/tags/${TAG_NAME}
```