# Migrating SVN to git doesn't migrate the tags to Azure DevOps

Tags: git, azure, svn, azure-devops, migration

I'll migrate repositories from an own subversion server to a Azure DevOps git repository. For that I'm using next commands:

```bsh
# Cloning
git svn clone --stdlayout --authors-file=autors.txt "http://www.subversion.com/svn/<repoName>" <repoName>
Set-Location <repoName>

# Creation of the repository using the REST APIs of DevOps by a .NET application

# Pushing
git remote add origin "https://organisation@dev.azure.com/organisation/repoName/_git/repoName";
git push -u origin --all;
git push origin --tags;

# Pushing each branch
[string[]]$svnBranches = svn ls "http://www.subversion.com/svn/<repoName>/branches/";

$svnBranches | ForEach-Object {
    [string]$name = $_.TrimEnd("/");
    Write-Host $name;
    git checkout $name;
    git push;
}
```

The problem is that the tags aren't pushed to DevOps. I've searched everywhere and found [`git push origin --tags`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18216991/create-a-tag-in-a-github-repository) but this doesn't work.

I've created the workaround for the branches to keep them in the DevOps repository, otherwise they are removed too.

This workaround I can't reuse for the tags because `git tag -l` gives no results and `svn ls "http://www.subversion.com/svn/<repoName>/tags/"` this error:

> `svn: E170013:` Unable to connect to a repository at URL `http://www.subversion.com/svn/<repoName>/tags/`
>
> `svn: E175003:` The server at `http://www.subversion.com/svn/<repoName>/tags/` does not support the HTTP/DAV protocol

What else can I do to migrate the tags to the Azure DevOps git repository?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, you're saying your procedure is working for branches, but not for tags? Aren't they exactly the same in SVN?

Comment: @Keldorn: Your confusion comes maby because the procedure does a `svn ls` for the branches and checking every branch of the cloned git repository and pushing it. For the tags from SVN, I can do the `svn ls` too but I can't do create the tag in the cloned git respository and pushing it to Azure DevOps.

Answer (score 0):

Derived from [this post](https://john.albin.net/git/convert-subversion-to-git), here is what we are using (not using DevOps, but worked on GitLab and GitHub):

```
git svn clone https://.......
# Create repo on hosting service
cd <the-repo.git>
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/remotes/origin/tags | cut -d/ -f5 | while read ref; do 
  git tag -a "$ref" -m "$(git log --pretty=oneline refs/remotes/origin/tags/$ref | head -n1 | cut -d' ' -f2-)" "refs/remotes/origin/tags/$ref"
  git update-ref -d "refs/remotes/origin/tags/$ref"
done
git remote add origin .............
git push origin 'refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/heads/*'
git push origin --tags
```

Comment: It gives me an error on the `do` keyword saying: _Missing statement body in do loop._

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should the following command to push data to DevOps:

```
git push -u --all --follow-tags origin
```

With this command, everything should be sent to the origin, including tags.

By the way, there's another tool that allows translating data from SVN to Git, its name is SubGit:

https://subgit.com

It allows to import more sophisticated repositories, probably, can be helpful in what you're doing.