# How to assign a tag to the orphaned commit in GitHub?

Tags: git, github, orphaned-objects

I have an orphaned commit produced by another person, and I see it in GitHub GUI. This commit is not accessible by cloning the repository as there are no branches/tags that contain this commit on the path. Assuming that the author of the commit has removed his local repository, I wish to assign a branch/tag to this commit directly in GitHub.

This commit can be seen just using a direct link that I can use because it's git hash is known. The commit is not seen in the *Insights>Network* however.

How can I assign a tag to the commit from this commit page in GitHub? Is that possible to create a new branch directly from this page? What are other ways to return this commit back in service?

Comment: Are you able to assign that commit object to a "release" to bring it back in service? As in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18216991/create-a-tag-in-a-github-repository - Then it also becomes a tag.

Comment: That doesn't work as the *Target:* doesn't have this commit in the list of *Recent Commits*. The orphaned commit is one year old.

Comment: I think i found something. Go to `https://github.com/<user>/<repo>/tree/<orphan-commit>`.  Select the dropdown for that hash in the upper left corner of the file list and create a new branch based on that commit. https://pasteboard.co/JvYJdgo.png

Comment: Based on your recommendation I've found a way to create a Pull Request from this commit to any other branch. That should work to solve my issue. I'm not sure how did you create the branch (did you do that without a PR?), but if you answer with the explanation, I'd accept your answer.

Comment: I'll clarify in an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Making an orphan commit cloneable again

Orphan commits that reside only on the remote (as long as garbage collection allows) cannot be cloned.

Through the Github web interface, using a direct link (e.g. `https://github.com/<user>/<repository>/tree/<orphan-commit>`) to the tree object connected to an orphan commit, you can access the **Create Branch** interface to create a new branch based on `<orphan-commit>` (which you already know the hash of) and make the object cloneable again.

[image]