# Git can't create tag in Azure DevOps

Tags: git, azure, composer-php

I've a Azure Devops pipeline that build  commit version and tag in my application.

I use, `composer-version minor|major|patch` to create application version , that write version in `composer.json`

Also, i use `git push -u origin HEAD:master --tags` to commit the version of my application. This command can push the file that have the version, but can't create new tag.

Can someone have an idea about this ?

Comment: What **exactly** is not working? How is this related to Composer?

Comment: I can't find tag in repos

Comment: @QuentinMerlin Have you had a chance to check the provided solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the official git doc, `git push --tags` command only pushes all refs under refs/tags, in addition to refspecs explicitly listed on the command line.

For creating a new tag, you'd have to use:

```
git tag <tagname>
```

or for creating an annotated tag:

```
git tag <tagname> -a
```

You can then push the tag after you create it. Check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18216991/create-a-tag-in-a-github-repository) for other detailed discussions on tags in GitHub.