# Repository on Github

Tags: linux, github, repository

How to configure the repository on GitHub, so that you can install the program (any version, and there will be two in one repository), without cloning the entire repository.
The cloning is to be done via the Linux. The program is packaged in the .tar.gz format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tags` to have multiple versions of a package

the article below will guide you

[Create a tag in a GitHub repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18216991/create-a-tag-in-a-github-repository)

Comment: A tag lets you _identify_ a version, but it doesn't allow you to pull down just those versions of those files without cloning the repository.

Comment: After each `tag (version)` you can manually download zip and tar file of that version without having new codes (that are in the new version) using git hosts like github

Comment: oh, thanks! Your answers solved my problem.