# How to create tag with forward slash in its name

Tags: git, tags, git-tag

Is there any way to create git tag with forward slash in its name when I already have the similar-looking one?

Suppose that I have "1.16.0" tag and I want to create "1.16.0/1.0.0" tag:

```
$ git tag "1.16.0/1.0.0"
error: 'refs/tags/1.16.0' exists; cannot create 'refs/tags/1.16.0/1.0.0'
fatal: refs/tags/1.16.0/1.0.0: cannot lock the ref
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not possible. See, the name of tag (any reference, in fact; the same goes with branches) is treated as the name of the file system object, created in `$GIT_DIR/refs` folder of your repository. This object stores the hash commit the tag is attached to.

With tag `foo`, it's easy - file `foo` is created in `$GIT_DIR/refs`, nothing special to wonder about.

With tag `foo/bar`, however, it's a bit more complicated: now *folder* `foo` is created, having just a single file - `bar` (again, with the hash commit). Quoting [the docs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-check-ref-format.html):

> [reference names] can include slash / for hierarchical (directory) grouping

The problem is, it's not possible to have two objects - file and folder - with the same name. So if you already have `1.16.0` tag, you won't be able to work with `1.16.0/anything`. One obvious solution is transforming that initial tag into something like `1.16.0/0.0.1`, then proceeding with your original intent. Or you can just replace slash with `-` or `_`.