# Getting Error while creating the new tag in my local git clone

Tags: git, git-tag

I already have tag with name of "V1.8/INTERNAL", Then I'm trying to create the new tag with name of "V1.8" by using following command.

```
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe -C D:\IOT_GIT\WinPkg tag -a  V1.8 3b87e27 -m  "" --force
```

But, I'm getting the following error,

```
fatal: cannot lock ref 'refs/tags/V1.8': 'refs/tags/V1.8/INTERNAL' exists; cannot create 'refs/tags/V1.8'
```

When I saw in TortoiseGit the new tag created successfully. I don't know why this error is coming while creating that new tag.

Comment: It seems /internal is not recognized as part of tag but as subfolder. Thus git thinks v1.8 exist.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create tag with forward slash in its name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32849840/how-to-create-tag-with-forward-slash-in-its-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible workaround would be to adopt different naming convention for:

- namespace tags (for instance: `1.8/INTERNAL`)
- regular tags (v1.8)

That way, you avoid having a tag name which is the same as a tag namespace (translated as a folder withing `refs`)

You can rename you existing `V1.8/INTERNAL` tag, then add your regular `V1.8` tag.