# what is the difference between getPeeledObjectId() and getObjectId() of Ref Object?

Tags: java, git, github, jgit

I am using jgit api for my project's build, deployment functionalities (**in Local Machine**). I commited whole source (java project) via command prompt by following commands

1. `git add .`
2. `git commit -a -m "Initial_Source"`

   Here I get the commit id as `cb96c685a5a4338f852a782631df8d1cf5dca21d`
3. `git tag Initial_Source cb96c685a5a4338f852a782631df8d1cf5dca21d`

   [cb96c685a5a4338f852a782631df8d1cf5dca21d is commitid]
4. `git push`
5. `git push --tags`

but when i tried to get commit id via getPeeledObjectId() it is returning `null`

my code is

```
Ref tag = git.getRepository().getRef("Initial_Source");
Ref peeledRef = git.getRepository().peel(tag);
return peeledRef.getPeeledObjectId(); -- this is returning null
```

but instead of `getPeeledObjectId()` I tried using `getObjectId()`. It's giving the commitId. But I wanna know when to use `getPeelObjectId()` and `getObjectId()`.

What are those methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The getPeeledObjectId() method is always null on a [non-annotated (lightweight) tag](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging):

```
 git tag Initial_Source cb96c685a5a4338f852a782631df8d1cf5dca21d
```

That would work with an annotated tag

```
git tag -a Initial_Source cb96c685a5a4338f852a782631df8d1cf5dca21d
# or
git tag -m "Initial Source" Initial_Source cb96c685a5a4338f852a782631df8d1cf5dca21d
```

Since your tag is a pointer to a *commit* (referenced by `git.getRepository().peel(tag)`), `getObjectId()` gets its id, there is nothing to "peel" again: you already have the commit.
See "[What is the difference between an annotated and unannotated tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11514075/6309)"

See [`porcelain/ListTags.java` example](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/f01714f1fda6cafad9850194d76c182508702907/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/ListTags.java#L42-L54): it takes into account the two kinds of tag:

```
List<Ref> call = git.tagList().call();
for (Ref ref : call) {
    System.out.println("Tag: " + ref + " " + ref.getName() + " " + ref.getObjectId().getName());

    // fetch all commits for this tag
    LogCommand log = git.log();

    Ref peeledRef = repository.peel(ref);
    if(peeledRef.getPeeledObjectId() != null) {
        // Annotated tag
        log.add(peeledRef.getPeeledObjectId());
    } else {
        // Lightweight tag
        log.add(ref.getObjectId());
    }
}
```

Comment: wat is peel? where should i use getPeelObjectId() nd normal getObjectId()

Comment: @Jothivignesh peel is dereferencing the object: for a lightweight tag, there is nothing to dereference: it already points to the commit. For an annotated tag, you need `getPeelObjectId()` in order to access the commit, because `getObjectId()` would give you the tag itself. That is part of the difference between lightweight and annotated tag, as described in the answers of https://stackoverflow.com/q/11514075/6309.

Comment: so if i put a tag with -a or -m(annotated tag) then i can get the commitId from getPeelObjectId() otherwise i have to use getObjectId().. rit?

Comment: @Jothivignesh Yes, that is the idea.

Answer (score 0):

- As @VonC said i think we cannot get ObjectId of a lightweight tag(i.e
  a tag without -a or -m) from getPeeledObjectId().
- I tried to commit a file and tag that file without -a or -m

  [ **git
  tag Initial_Source cb96c685a5a4338f852a782631df8d1cf5dca21d** ].
- Then run a java main program to get object Id from
  getPeeledObjectId() which obviously returns null.
- Then i commit a file and then tag it with -a and -m (any 1 is enough
  to act as annotated tag)

  [ **git tag Appinterface 523a05f9c486e64eba29786a1b8abfc4da421260 -m "Appinterface_commit_tag"** ]
- Now i am getting objectId from getPeeledObjectId()