# How to log the commits between two release tags with JGit

Tags: jgit

I have one case which is for example to run git command like

```
$ git log 1.0.201802090918...1.0.201802071240"
```

to get a differed commits list between release tag 1.0.201802090918 and 1.0.201802071240 under my repo. So I wonder how to code with JGit to gain the same here.

Comment: I see you are new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, I will spend some time to give a try with the provided suggestion, and will follow this rule once it proves to be working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LogCommand` allows to specify the range of commits that it will include. The range need to be given as `ObjectId`s. And if tags mark the start and end points, the commit IDs that they reference need to be extracted first.

The snippet below illustrates the necessary steps:

```java
ObjectId from = repo.resolve("refs/tags/start-tag");
ObjectId to = repo.resolve("refs/tags/end-tag");
git.log().addRange(from, to).call();
```

If annotated tags are used, they may have to be *unpeeled* first as described here: [what is the difference between getPeeledObjectId() and getObjectId() of Ref Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44692822/what-is-the-difference-between-getpeeledobjectid-and-getobjectid-of-ref-obje)