# Difference between tag and commit message

Tags: git, git-commit, git-tag

I understand one always needs a message for committing the changes but when and why do I need to also tag a commit? Let's say I made some changes and I commit using

```
git add -A
git commit -m "add feature 1"
```

and now

```
git tag -a -m "includes feature 1" v0.1
```

The question is when does this make sense.

Comment: You do not need to tag. You can also make a lightweight tag if you don't supply -a and -m. See https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging

Comment: Read the DESCRIPTION section of `git help tag`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It would make sense to specify a tag when you release a version of the software you're producing.

You could then do:

`git tag -a v1.0 -m "Release Version 1.0"`

Like my comment mentioned, you do not have to tag after every commit, like you mention in your post, you can also create lightweight tags, if you don't want to include a message. This would look like:

`git tag v1.0`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 27):

First, let's define the difference between a *commit*, a *branch name* and a *tag name*.  Then I'll outsource the rest of this to the existing question and excellent answer at [What is the difference between an annotated and unannotated tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11514075/1256452)  Note that a *lightweight tag* (un-annotated) does not take a message; only an *annotated* tag takes a message.

#### Defining a commit

A *commit* is an *object* in a Git repository.  Git repository objects are mostly-permanent and completely read-only, and are consistency-checked so that they are incorruptible.  There are four kinds of objects: commits (which we'll describe in detail in a moment), *trees*, *blobs*, and *annotated tag objects*.  All four kinds are identified by hash IDs.

A *blob* is, very roughly, where Git stores your file's contents: if your `README` file says `I am a readme file`, the string `I am a readme file` is stored as a *blob*.  A *tree* object is, slightly oversimplified, the thing that stores the file's *name* along with the blob hash ID of the file's contents.  Hence, in order for commit `1234567...` to store your `README` file, Git has a tree that says "file `README` has contents from blob `c3c2a8983de728ffcf8f0ccaad014349925f23e6`".<sup>1</sup>

In any case, each commit stores one *tree* hash ID, which is the saved snapshot of your source files<sup>2</sup> at the time you made the commit.  It also stores the hash ID of the *parent* commit(s) of this commit, so that Git can work backwards through the history to find all commits.  It stores your name and email address and a timestamp, as the person who made the commit and when.<sup>3</sup>

After these required items—tree, parent(s), author, and committer—Git adds your *log message*, which is entirely arbitrary as far as Git itself is concerned.  You don't have to supply any log message at all, and if you do supply one, it does not have to make sense.  It will, however, be *shown* to you, and to other people, when they explore the history—the commits—stored in the repository.

#### Commits form chains, which is history

Because each commit records its earlier *parent* commit, the set of commits forms a chain that can be read backwards:

```
A  <-B  <-C   <--master
```

Git can start with a *name*, like the branch name `master`, to get the hash ID of commit `C` (whatever its real hash ID may be: I use `C` here as shorthand instead of the actual hash).  This hash ID is unique to commit `C`: no other commit anywhere has that same hash ID.<sup>4</sup>  Commit `C` itself stores the hash ID of commit `B`, so from `C` we can find `B`.  `B` stores the hash ID of commit `A`, so from `B` we can find `A`.

This particular repository has only three commits: `A` is the *root* commit, the first one we ever made, so it has no parent, and that lets us stop following history.

#### Branch and tag names find commits

But this also tells us what a branch name is and does: **A *branch name* is a name that identifies a commit, by the commit's hash ID.  A *tag name* does the same thing.**  So now we might wonder: what's the difference?  When should we use a branch name, and when should we use a tag name?

Aside from the issue of name spaces,<sup>6</sup> the main difference is that Git will let us get "on" a branch name, using `git checkout`.  Once we are on such a branch, creating a *new* commit has a side effect: it *changes the hash ID associated with the branch name*.  If we check out `master` and make a *new commit*, the parent ID stored in the new commit is the ID of `C`.  Whatever the *new* commit's hash ID is, as computed by Git, that new hash ID goes into the name `master`, so that we now have:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
```

The name `master` now *points to* new commit `D`, which points back to `C`, which points back to `B`, and so on.  The branch has grown, and the *branch name* points to the *latest* commit.  Each commit points back to a previous one.

You cannot get "on" a tag like this.  The *tag name* `v1.0`, once it's set to point to commit `C`, continues to point to commit `C`, forever.  So this is the main difference between a branch name and a tag name in Git: **A branch name changes over time, and even does this automatically when you make commits.  A tag name should never<sup>7</sup> change.**

---

<sup>1</sup>`c3c2a8983de728ffcf8f0ccaad014349925f23e6` is the hash ID of the content that reads `I am a readme file`.  You can find this by running the following shell command:

```
$ echo 'I am a readme file' | git hash-object -t blob --stdin
c3c2a8983de728ffcf8f0ccaad014349925f23e6
```

Note that any blob object anywhere in any Git repository in the universe has this hash ID if it has this content!  The content must consist of just those 19 bytes, including the terminating newline (with no carriage-return).

<sup>2</sup>More precisely, it's the saved *index*, aka *staging area* aka *cache*, as written out by `git write-tree`.

<sup>3</sup>Git stores these twice, once as the *author* of the commit and again as the *committer*.  The two become different if you are, e.g., taking someone else's commit that they emailed you, and inserting it into a repository: then the *author* is the one who sent you the commit, but you are the *committer*.  There are other situations in which the two become different.  For the most part, nobody cares much, but run `git log --pretty=fuller` to see both.

<sup>4</sup>Hash IDs *can* repeat in *different* repositories, but only if the two repositories are never brought together.  To make sure that commit hash IDs are unique, Git includes those time-stamps.  This ensures even if you make the *same* commit you made before, with the same tree and same parent and same log message, if you make it at a different *time*, it's a different *commit*.  (If you make it at the *same* time, then it's really exactly the same, and why do you care if you make it once or make it twice?<sup>5</sup>)

<sup>5</sup>There is a potential reason to care, but it's quite obscure and mostly irrelevant.

<sup>6</sup>Technically, a branch name is a *reference* that starts with `refs/heads/`, e.g., `refs/heads/master` is full spelling of the `master` branch.  A tag name is a reference that starts with `refs/tags/`, such as `refs/tags/v1.0`.  These are the reference *name spaces*, which include `refs/remotes/`, `refs/notes/`, `refs/replace/`, and `refs/stash` as well.

<sup>7</sup>Well, hardly ever.  Some people really want a "floating tag".  You *can* do this in Git, if you are careful and know what you are doing.  There's no real point, though: if you want a name that moves, use a branch name.  That's what they do.  If you want a name that doesn't move, use a tag name.  That's what *they* do.