# GitLab CI - avoid build when adding tag

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

How do I prevent a gitlab ci pipeline being triggered when I add a git tag? I'm running this command locally (as opposed to within a gitlab-ci job)

```
git tag -a "xyz"
```

and then pushing the tag; and this triggers various pipelines. I want to exclude some of those pipelines from running.

I'm trying variations on ideas from questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49514416/trigger-gitlab-ci-pipeline-only-when-there-is-a-new-tag); that question is using **only**, I'm wanting to exclude, so I'm trying except. The answers there have two variants, one with **refs** one without.

```
build:  
  # ... my work here ...  
  except:
    - tags


build:  
  # ... my work here ...  
  except:
    refs:
      - tags
```

Neither seem to have any effect; I add a tag, the build still happens.

My understanding may be completely awry here as there seem to be three possible meanings of the word **tags** and when reading docs or examples I'm not always sure which meaning is applicable:

1. Git tags applied using **git tag**
2. Gitlab CI tags used to determine which runners pick a job
3. The **ref** identifier of a commit used to trigger a pipeline via the REST API. This is usually a branch name, but could be a git tag.

I'm interested in controlling what happens if the first case. It does seem clear from comments so far that "except: -tags" is not relevant to my case, so is there any approach that does work?

Comment: Per https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-basic  this refers to git tags. You can also see info on the refs strategy on that page. Note that there will be two builds for a tagged commit; one for the commit, one for the tag.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe. I agree that's what the docs say is the sense of "tag". Is there any way to prevent these builds cause by git tags?

Comment: Are you using `git tag -a TAG` locally and then `git push origin TAG`? Or the `git tag` command is part of your `.gitlab-ci.yml` jobs ?

Comment: @Nicolas Pepinster - running locally and pushing, added that clarification

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`Except tags` is exactly what you should use if you want to skip build for tags.

You need to be sure to understand [commit vs branches vs tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49415064/10950272)

To illustrate what happens when you push tagged commit to gitlab I did as follows:

1. Created `.gitlab-ci.yml` with following content:

```yaml
tests_always_run:
    script:
      - echo I should always execute
tests_except_tags:
    script:
      - echo I skip tagged triggers
    except:
      - tags
```

2. Commited changes, tagged commit and pushed with `--follow-tags` to make sure tag is also propagated to server:

```sh
git add .gitlab-ci.yml
git commit -m 'my great yml with except tags'
git tag -a "abc" -m "Test tag"
git push --follow-tags
```

Ilustrated results:
[image: Tagged commit pipeline results]

If you want to skip CI for selected commit then you could use [git push -o ci.skip](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/push_options.html#push-options-for-gitlab-cicd), inspired by [this article](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/8222/20039)

Answer (score 40):

It looks like GitLab recommends using `rules` instead of `except` as per [the documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#only--except)

> only and except are not being actively developed. rules is the
> preferred keyword to control when to add jobs to pipelines.

So it'd be

```
your_job:
  stage: your_stage
  script:
    - echo "Hello"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
      when: never 
    - when: always
```

Comment: @diegosaw, thanks. We are still on v12 where the docs say: "Note: The rules syntax is now the preferred method of setting job policies. only and except are candidates for deprecation, and may be removed in the future." I'm glad you drew this to my attention.

Comment: Note that this may lead to pipelines being executed twice if you push to a branch for which a merge request exists. Details here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#avoid-duplicate-pipelines

Comment: BTW last rule can be on success instead of always.

Answer (score 6):

(note : this a formatted comment more than an answer)

In order to debug the conditions that trigger your pipeline :

[gitlab's doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) mentions several variables which are set when running a CI job, among which :

> - `CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` : The branch or tag name for which project is built
> - `CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` : The commit branch name. Present only when building branches.
> - `CI_COMMIT_TAG` : The commit tag name. Present only when building tags.

Have your build job output some of these variables (e.g : `echo "triggered by ref : " $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME`) to view what triggered your job.

Answer (score 1):

I was in the same situation, my solution was this:

Before::
[image: BEFORE]

After:
[image: AFTER]

Both stages are configured in my .gitlab-ci.yml file,  with different name
The "**Dev-UnitTests**" , it only executes when someone commits to the repository, no effect on  **tags** y the branch "**test**"

```
Dev-UnitTests:
  stage: pruebas 
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS test
  artifacts:
    when: always
    reports:
      junit: 
        - target/surefire-reports/*Test.xml
        - target/failsafe-reports/*Test.xml
      cobertura: target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml
  tags:
    - shell 
  except: 
    - test 
    - tags
```

The **Unit Tests** , only run when a merge is done on the branch **test**

```
Unit Tests:
  stage: pruebas 
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS test
  artifacts:
    when: always
    reports:
      junit: 
        - target/surefire-reports/*Test.xml
        - target/failsafe-reports/*Test.xml
      cobertura: target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml
  tags:
    - shell 
  only: 
    - test
```

---

That did not run again any pipeline when creating a tag, I hope it helps you.

The key is:

```
...
 except:  
    - tags   
...
```

Answer (score 1):

For avoiding the whole pipeline, use “-o ci.skip”:

```
git tag -a "v1.0.0" -m "Release version 1.0.0"
git push origin "v1.0.0" -o ci.skip
```