# Tag Git repo with Python Package version from Azure Pipelines in Azure DevOps Git repo

Tags: python, git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

## Context

We use Azure DevOps for our Git Repos, Azure Pipelines for our CI/CD and Azure Artifacts for our private hosting of our python packages.

## Goal

I want to:

> Tag a Git repo with Python Package version from Azure Pipelines in Azure DevOps Git repo

**Example**

```sh
git tag -a "$(python setup.py --version)" -m "Released version $(python setup.py --version)"
```

I have read the Azure documentation but it seems they all use the Azure Pipeline variables for build number.

On a build pipeline, there is a check box to tag the repo on successfully building the wheel artifact.

[image: Image of 'Get Sources Job' option to tag a release on success]

But I'm not sure how to expose the package version as a pipeline variable since this job has no spot for me to escape to perform custom code. I'm sure there is a way to do it but I'm at the point where I need help and the documentation isn't guiding me to the right places based on what I'm querying and reading.

Comment: I gave you an upvote because I think this is a reasonable well thought out question and I don't like it when people downvote without an explanation.

Comment: Could you run a bash script to tag it after the build? It would look a bit more manual, but gives you the option to run custom code like you want, and it can use pipeline variables that you can set for the build

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not happy with this approach but it achieves the outcome.

Thanks @C.Nivs for the suggestion to just have a crack at a Bash script between the wheel successfully building and the task that exports the build artifact.

```sh
# Get Package Version
export PACKAGE_VERSION="$(python setup.py --version)"
echo "Package Version: v${PACKAGE_VERSION}"

# Get the body of the last merge commit message
git log HEAD~1..HEAD --format="RELEASE:v${PACKAGE_VERSION} Notes:%s%n%b"
export TAG_MESSAGE=$(git log HEAD~1..HEAD --format="RELEASE:v${PACKAGE_VERSION} Notes:%s%n%b")
echo $TAG_MESSAGE

# Set the config for the CI to be able to commit a tag
git config --global user.email "ci-pipeline@myorganisation.com"
git config --global user.name "Azure Pipelines: python-wheel-artifact"

# Create the tag locally as an annotated tag
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11514075/what-is-the-difference-between-an-annotated-and-unannotated-tag
git tag -a "v$PACKAGE_VERSION" -m "$TAG_MESSAGE"

# Update the push remote as the Personal Access Token URL
# Inject these values from the Pipeline variables.
git remote set-url --push origin "https://$(tag_push_username):$(tag_push_personal_access_token)@dev.azure.com/<myorganization>/<myproject>/_git/<myreponame>"

# Ensure the source of truth receives the tag.
git push --tags
```

**References:**

- [What is the difference between an annotated and unannotated tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11514075/what-is-the-difference-between-an-annotated-and-unannotated-tag)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, if so, would you please accept your solution as the answer? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)